# Tag not defined for this message type

Tags: c++, quickfix

I have problem with quickFix 4.2 :

```
58=Tag not defined for this message type|371=15|372=X
```

I know what it mean, but I already have this tag in my message **X**:

```
  <message name='MarketDataIncrementalRefresh' msgtype='X' msgcat='app'>
   <field name='MDReqID' required='N' />
   <group name='NoMDEntries' required='Y'>
    <field name='MDUpdateAction' required='Y' />
    <field name='Currency' required='N' />           <------ 15 tag
    <field name='DeleteReason' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryType' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryID' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryRefID' required='N' />
    <field name='Symbol' required='N' />
    <field name='SymbolSfx' required='N' />
    <field name='SecurityID' required='N' />
    <field name='IDSource' required='N' />
    <field name='SecurityType' required='N' />
    <field name='MaturityMonthYear' required='N' />
    <field name='MaturityDay' required='N' />
    <field name='PutOrCall' required='N' />
    <field name='StrikePrice' required='N' />
    <field name='OptAttribute' required='N' />
    <field name='ContractMultiplier' required='N' />
    <field name='CouponRate' required='N' />
    <field name='SecurityExchange' required='N' />
    <field name='Issuer' required='N' />
    <field name='EncodedIssuerLen' required='N' />
    <field name='EncodedIssuer' required='N' />
    <field name='SecurityDesc' required='N' />
    <field name='EncodedSecurityDescLen' required='N' />
    <field name='EncodedSecurityDesc' required='N' />
    <field name='FinancialStatus' required='N' />
    <field name='CorporateAction' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryPx' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntrySize' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryDate' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryTime' required='N' />
    <field name='TickDirection' required='N' />
    <field name='MDMkt' required='N' />
    <field name='TradingSessionID' required='N' />
    <field name='QuoteCondition' required='N' />
    <field name='TradeCondition' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryOriginator' required='N' />
    <field name='LocationID' required='N' />
    <field name='DeskID' required='N' />
    <field name='OpenCloseSettleFlag' required='N' />
    <field name='TimeInForce' required='N' />
    <field name='ExpireDate' required='N' />
    <field name='ExpireTime' required='N' />
    <field name='MinQty' required='N' />
    <field name='ExecInst' required='N' />
    <field name='SellerDays' required='N' />
    <field name='OrderID' required='N' />
    <field name='QuoteEntryID' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryBuyer' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntrySeller' required='N' />
    <field name='NumberOfOrders' required='N' />
    <field name='MDEntryPositionNo' required='N' />
    <field name='TotalVolumeTraded' required='N' />
    <field name='Text' required='N' />
    <field name='EncodedTextLen' required='N' />
    <field name='EncodedText' required='N' />
    <field name='TotalValueTraded' required='N' /> <------ Tag 6143
    <field name='SettlmntTyp' required='N' />
    <field name='TradeDate' required='N' />
    </group>
  </message>
```

This message I receive:

```
20211210-18:08:38.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.2|9=404|35=X|49=SenderCompID|56=TargetCompID|34=3|52=20211210-18:08:38|262=0|75=20211210|268=2|279=0|269=0|270=296.72|271=10|273=19:05:01|22=4|48=ISINID|100=exdest|55=Symbol|63=0|15=SUR|120=SUR|326=17|336=OPEN|387=90000920|6143=26826409296.00|279=0|269=1|270=296.75|271=30|273=19:04:41|22=4|48=ISINID|100=exdest|55=Symbol|63=0|15=SUR|120=SUR|326=17|336=OPEN|387=90000920|6143=26826409296.00|10=233|
```

I added new tag 6143 in xml:

```
<field number='6143' name='TotalValueTraded' type='FLOAT' />
```

And tag 6143 already exist in MarketDataIncrementalRefresh Msg

What  I do wrong If all tags exist in my FIX42.xml? Thanks

Comment: I solved my problem, it was because I did not add tag number 75 at UP-level. I added it into group, but it was wrong

Comment: Copy/paste your comment into an answer, and then mark it as answered.